# GNUTLS Client-Server TLS handshake error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnutls

I am using two sample examples given by gnutls:

1. "Simple client example with X.509 certificate support" without any change
2. "Echo server with X.509 authentication". I have generated the private key "key.pem" using certtool and self-signed certificate "cert.pem" and use it within the example.

   The server works correctly... the output is the following:

   > Server ready. Listening to port '5556'

But if I run the client example, it return the following error:

> **Handshake failed GnuTLS error: The TLS connection was non-properly
>   terminated**

and the server returns:

> **connection from 127.0.0.1, port 58587  Handshake has failed (The request is invalid.)**

What is the problem? Do I need to change the client example? If not, how can I check the TLS handshake process and the data sent between the client and server?

Comment: Similar problem with the anonymous connection example. Handshake fails. Have you found a solution?